# Context.Enter always fails in CEF3

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I'm having some issues when converting a CEF1 project to CEF3, using the latest Delphi Chromium Embedded code in the repo (3.1750.1738). To be brief, I used to have an extension that I would register. Then on the html side, I would use a native call to register a javascript object with the Delphi host. It would store the object and the object's context for later calls. But this doesn't seem to work with DCEF3. I can get the object and it's context. But later when I call `context.Enter`, it fails. I am wondering if this has to do with changes in the architecture between cef1 and cef3. I already had to change up the extension a bit to register it in `OnWebkitIniitalized`.

Here's my code:

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, cefvcl, ceflib, StdCtrls;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Guest: ICefv8Value;
    GuestContext: ICefv8Context;
    Browser: TChromium;
    procedure BrowserConsoleMessage(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
      const message, source: ustring; line: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
  public
    function ExtensionExecute(const name: ustring; const obj: ICefv8Value;
      const arguments: TCefv8ValueArray; var retval: ICefv8Value;
      var exception: ustring): Boolean;
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  BrowserExt: TCefv8HandlerOwn;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  code =
   'var cef;'+
   'if (!cef)'+
   '  cef = {};'+
   'if (!cef.nes)'+
   '  cef.nes = {};'+
   '(function() {'+
   '  cef.nes.callNative = function() {'+
   '    native function callNative();'+
   '    return callNative.apply(this, arguments);'+
   '  };'+
   '})();';

type
  TCustomRenderProcessHandler = class(TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn)
  protected
    procedure OnWebKitInitialized; override;
  end;

  TExtension = class(TCefv8HandlerOwn)
  protected
    function Execute(const name: ustring; const obj: ICefv8Value;
      const arguments: TCefv8ValueArray; var retval: ICefv8Value;
      var exception: ustring): Boolean; override;
  public
    Host: TMainForm;
  end;

function TExtension.Execute(const name: ustring; const obj: ICefv8Value;
  const arguments: TCefv8ValueArray; var retval: ICefv8Value;
  var exception: ustring): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Host.ExtensionExecute(name, obj, arguments, retval, exception);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  o: ICefv8Value;
begin
  if GuestContext.Enter then
  begin
    o := Guest.GetValueByKey('foo');
    OutputDebugString(PChar('foo found now: ' + BoolToStr(Assigned(o), True)));
    GuestContext.Exit;
  end
  else
    OutputDebugString('GuestContext.Enter failed');
end;

function TMainForm.ExtensionExecute(const name: ustring; const obj: ICefv8Value;
  const arguments: TCefv8ValueArray; var retval: ICefv8Value;
  var exception: ustring): Boolean;
var
  o: ICefv8Value;
begin
  OutputDebugStringW(PWideChar('Execute: ' + name));
  if name = 'callNative' then
  begin
    GuestContext := TCefv8ContextRef.Current;
    Guest := arguments[0];

    o := Guest.GetValueByKey('foo');
    OutputDebugString(PChar('foo found: ' + BoolToStr(Assigned(o), True)));
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Browser := TChromium.Create(Self);

  Browser.Options.JavascriptDomPaste := STATE_DISABLED;
  Browser.Options.CaretBrowsing := STATE_DISABLED;

  Browser.OnConsoleMessage := BrowserConsoleMessage;

  Browser.Color := clWhite;
  Browser.Align := alClient;

  Browser.DefaultUrl := 'http://localhost/test2/home.html';

  Browser.Parent := Self;

  BrowserExt := TExtension.Create;
  TExtension(BrowserExt).Host := Self;

  Browser.Load(Browser.DefaultUrl);
end;

procedure TMainForm.BrowserConsoleMessage(Sender: TObject;
    const browser: ICefBrowser; const message, source: ustring; line: Integer;
    out Result: Boolean);
begin
  OutputDebugStringW(PWideChar('[line ' + IntToStr(Line) + '] ' + message));
end;

{ TCustomRenderProcessHandler }

procedure TCustomRenderProcessHandler.OnWebKitInitialized;
begin
  inherited;

  CefRegisterExtension('v8/nes', code, BrowserExt as ICefV8Handler);
end;

initialization
  CefRemoteDebuggingPort := 9000;
  CefRenderProcessHandler := TCustomRenderProcessHandler.Create;
  CefBrowserProcessHandler := TCefBrowserProcessHandlerOwn.Create;

end.
```

And the javascript code:

```
console.log('startup');

var guest = {foo:function() {
  console.log('foo called');

  return 42;
}};

if (typeof(cef) !== "undefined") {
  console.log('registering guest');

  cef.nes.callNative(guest);
}
else {
  console.log('no cef');
}

console.log('startup done');
```

`TMainForm.ExtensionExecute` is triggered and callNative happens. But later when I do Button1Click, the context Enter always returns False.

Comment: Also, if from Button1 I check Browser.Browser.MainFrame.Getv8Context, I get nil. When trying the same thing in DCEF1, I get a valid context.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that I'm using single process mode to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the CEF3 architecture changing to multi-thread/process. You can no longer just call code directly but must pass messages back and forth using Browser.SendProcessMessage and handle them with OnProcessMessage handlers.